# Google studio dynamic query dynamic column name

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

Let's say I have below query

```
select sum(tab1.name),dt.month from tab1
inner join date_tab dt on dt.full_year = tab1.dob_year
group by dt.month
```

Now this grouping and last column may change dynamically

```
select sum(tab1.name),dt.year from tab1
inner join date_tab dt on dt.full_year = tab1.dob_year
group by dt.year
```

So I believe I can change the group by column like

```
 select sum(tab1.name),dt.month from tab1
    inner join date_tab dt on dt.full_year = tab1.dob_year
    group by @dt_group_coumn
```

But I have requirement like

```
select sum(tab1.name),@dt_group_coumn from tab1
inner join date_tab dt on dt.full_year = tab1.dob_year
group by @dt_group_coumn
```

How Can I achieve this..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case:

```
SELECT SUM(tab1.name),
       CASE 
         WHEN @dt_group_column = 'dt.month' THEN dt.month 
         WHEN @dt_group_column = 'dt.year' THEN dt.year 
         ELSE NULL 
       END AS group_column
FROM tab1
INNER JOIN date_tab dt ON dt.full_year = tab1.dob_year
GROUP BY group_column;
```

- use `CASE` to determine which column to use for the group by based on the value of `@dt_group_column`.

`@dt_group_column` set `dt.month`, group by dt.month | set to `dt.year`, group by dt.year | set to any other value, no group by.

GROUP BY now uses the `group_column` alias instead of the `@dt_group_column`. variables aren't not allowed in `GROUP BY` .

Dynamic SQL:

```
SET @dt_group_column = 'dt.month'; -- change this to the column you want to group by

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT SUM(tab1.name), ', @dt_group_column, ' FROM tab1
                   INNER JOIN date_tab dt ON dt.full_year = tab1.dob_year
                   GROUP BY ', @dt_group_column);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

- set the value of the `@dt_group_column variable` to the column you want to group by.
- `CONCAT` to dynamically build the SQL query string using value from `@dt_group_column`.
- prepare the statement and execute.

Ps. dynamic SQL makes your code complex and harder to maintain, it can also be a security risk if input values aren't properly validated